# Managing logs generated by user

Tags: database-design, restore, logs

I am developing a web app for my client and there is a section which displays the changes made in the application by any of the user. This section is known as log.It basically stores and displays the events triggered by the users. I am storing these logs in an external file for time being. But it seems as the client wants to perform certain operation on those logs too.

Hence, my question is that is it right to store all the log files in a database file instead of external file, because there are some limitations in file operation as we know. Also should we make a new table to store the log or associate it with the user in the user table.